# API functional testing using robot and jmeter

Tags: jmeter, robotframework, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am planning to automate REST API functional testing using jmeter and robot framework but unable to find any documentation for the same.If you guys have implemnted the same in any of your project can you pls share your experience also documentation link if any.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a lot of documentation, you just should be searching for these topics separately, example guides:

1. [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right)
2. [Robot Framework JMeter Library](https://github.com/kowalpy/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library)

From JMeter perspective it's only:

1. [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to send the request
2. [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to add [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) if needed
3. [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) for defining pass/fail criteria

And from Robot Framework you need to just execute JMeter's [.jmx test script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these Robot Framework libraries to test REST API:

- [Requests library](https://github.com/asyrjasalo/RESTinstance)
- [RESTinstance library](https://github.com/asyrjasalo/RESTinstance) (last updated at October 2019)